# Como mesclar valores idêntico de array, e colocar os diferentes dentro de um subarray

Tags: php, array

Estou com o seguinte problema.

Eu tenho um array retornado do banco de dados que está da seguinte forma:

```
array(4) {
[0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["groupoURL"]=> string(7) "express"
    ["grupoNome"]=> string(13) "Express"
    ["subgrupoURL"]=> string(4) "aves"
    ["subgrupoNome"]=> string(4) "Aves"
  }
[1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["groupoURL"]=> string(7) "express"
    ["grupoNome"]=> string(13) "Express"
    ["subgrupoURL"]=> string(4) "peixes"
    ["subgrupoNome"]=> string(4) "Peixes"
  }
[2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["groupoURL"]=> string(7) "executivo"
    ["grupoNome"]=> string(13) "Executivo"
    ["subgrupoURL"]=> string(4) "aves"
    ["subgrupoNome"]=> string(4) "Aves"
  }
[3]=>
  array(4) {
    ["groupoURL"]=> string(7) "executivo"
    ["grupoNome"]=> string(13) "Executivo"
    ["subgrupoURL"]=> string(4) "carnes"
    ["subgrupoNome"]=> string(4) "Carnes"
  }
}
```

Eu estou tentando mesclar os valores que são idênticos (No caso, sempre serão as chaves "grupoURL" e "grupoNome", e o restante "subgrupoURL" e "subgrupoNome" deverão se tornar um array e os seus valores serem unidos.

O meu resultado final precisaria ficar desta forma:

```
array(2) {
[0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["groupoURL"]=> string(7) "express"
    ["grupoNome"]=> string(13) "Express"
    ["subgrupos"]=> array(
        array(
            ["subgrupoURL"]=> "aves",
            ["subgrupoNome"]=> "Aves"
        ),
        array(
            ["subgrupoURL"]=> "peixes",
            ["subgrupoNome"]=> "Peixes"
        ),
    )
  }
[1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["groupoURL"]=> string(7) "executivo"
    ["grupoNome"]=> string(13) "Executivo"
    ["subgrupos"]=> array(
        array(
            ["subgrupoURL"]=> "aves",
            ["subgrupoNome"]=> "Aves"
        ),
        array(
            ["subgrupoURL"]=> "carnes",
            ["subgrupoNome"]=> "Carnes"
        ),
    )
  }
}
```

Ainda não tenho uma solução, mas estou tentando criar algo, mas esta não seria a forma ideal:

```
    $test = ...Recebe os resultados da consulta
    $newArray = [];
    foreach($test as $array) {
        switch ($array["groupoURL"]) {
            case "express":
                 $newArray["express"]["grupoNome"] = $array["grupoNome"];
                 $newArray["express"]["grupoURL"] = $array["groupoURL"];
                 $newArray["express"]["subgrupos"][] = ["subgrupoNome" => $array["subgrupoNome"], "subgrupoURL" => $array["subgrupoURL"]];
                 break;
            case "executivo":
                 $newArray["executivo"]["grupoNome"] = $array["grupoNome"];
                 $newArray["executivo"]["grupoURL"] = $array["groupoURL"];
                 $newArray["executivo"]["subgrupos"][] = ["subgrupoNome" => $array["subgrupoNome"], "subgrupoURL" => $array["subgrupoURL"]];
                 break;
            ...
            default: 
                break;
        }
    }
```

A solução acima funciona, porém eu estou verificando o "grupo" de cada item.
Pode acontecer do nome deste grupo ser alterado, ou um novo grupo ser inserido.

Alguém teria alguma sugestão?
Obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Atualize sua pergunta com o que tentou, para corrigirmos se houver necessidade.

Comment: Não seria melhor você ajustar sua query pra já retornar as informações nesse formato?

Comment: André, eu pensei no que você falou, para retornar os dados que preciso eu devo consultar em 3 tabelas, consegui um resultado alternativo usando o "GROUP_CONCAT".

No caso vai me retornar um registro para cada grupo e mais duas colunas, uma com os subgrupos separados por vírgula e outra com a url dos subgrupos.

[catN | catU | [subN, sub2n] | [subU, subU2]]

A partir disso eu teria que fazer um tratamento para chegar no resultado desejado.

Você teria alguma outra sugestão?
Pois eu acho que vou acabar ficando com esta segunda forma, apesar de eu estar curioso com a resposta da pergunta original

Comment: Precisa exatamente da estrutura que você postou? Outra maneira é usar os campos groupURL como key do array.

Comment: Algo parecido com isso: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/00d1354a27b821b245c8285f6aaf503accf8a98f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tá na mão:

```
<?php

$resultSet = [
    [
        'grupoURL'     => 'express',
        'grupoNome'    => 'Express',
        'subgrupoURL'  => 'aves',
        'subgrupoNome' => 'Aves'
    ],
    [
         'grupoURL'     => 'express',
         'grupoNome'    => 'Express',
         'subgrupoURL'  => 'peixes',
         'subgrupoNome' => 'Peixes'
    ],
    [
         'grupoURL'     => 'executivo',
         'grupoNome'    => 'Executivo',
         'subgrupoURL'  => 'aves',
         'subgrupoNome' => 'Aves'
    ],
    [
         'grupoURL'     => 'executivo',
         'grupoNome'    => 'Executivo',
         'subgrupoURL'  => 'carnes',
         'subgrupoNome' => 'Carnes'
    ]
];

$arrayFinal = [];

for ($i=0; $i<count($resultSet); $i++) {
    $inserido = false;
    for ($j=0; $j<count($arrayFinal); $j++) {
        if ($arrayFinal[$j]['grupoURL'] == $resultSet[$i]['grupoURL'] && $arrayFinal[$j]['grupoNome'] == $resultSet[$i]['grupoNome']) {
            $inserido = true;
            $arrayFinal[$j]['subgrupos'][] = [
                'subgrupoURL'  => $resultSet[$i]['subgrupoURL'],
                'subgrupoNome' => $resultSet[$i]['subgrupoNome']
            ];
        }
    }
    if (!$inserido) {
        $arrayFinal[] = [
            'grupoURL'  => $resultSet[$i]['grupoURL'],
            'grupoNome' => $resultSet[$i]['grupoNome'],
            'subgrupos' => [
                [
                    'subgrupoURL'  => $resultSet[$i]['subgrupoURL'],
                    'subgrupoNome' => $resultSet[$i]['subgrupoNome']
                ]
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

O que é feito: o *resultset* é percorrido e, a cada iteração, verifica-se as chaves `grupoNome` e `grupoURL` já estão presentes no array final. Se sim, colocamos os outros elementos como sub-elementos. Senão, criamos um novo índice no array final e os preenchemos com os dados do *resultset*.

Comment: Muuito obrigado, funcionou direitinho.